# Why is this android toolbar empty?

Tags: android, user-interface, toolbar, android-6.0-marshmallow, appbar

I have an activity with a toolbar but neither the back arrow nor the label of the activity is showing in the toolbar. I'm not sure why because I have another activity using seemingly identical code and the toolbar displays a back arrow and the activity label value set in manifest.xml.

```
<!--This is the activity where the toolbar doesn't work-->
<activity
        android:name=".CreateReviewActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_review"
        android:parentActivityName=".VenuesToReviewActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Phield">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.tremulant.phield.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
<!--This activity's toolbar works-->
<activity
        android:name=".ReviewDetailsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_review_details"
        android:parentActivityName=".VenuesToReviewActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Phield">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.tremulant.phield.VenuesToReviewActivity"/>
</activity>
```

The toolbar layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:flickr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
    flickr:theme="@style/ActionBarThemeOverlay"
    flickr:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBar.TitleText">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Strings for good measure

```
<string name="title_activity_create_review">Create Review</string>
<string name="title_activity_review_details">Review Details</string>
```

Layout that isn't working

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:phield="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/phieldBackgroundColor"
    tools:context=".CreateReviewActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Phield.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                phield:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Phield.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
        >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

        </LinearLayout>


java activity class that isn't working 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:phield="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/phieldBackgroundColor"
    tools:context=".CreateReviewActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Phield.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                phield:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Phield.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical"
        >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Java class that isn't working

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.tremulant.phield.data.Review;
import com.tremulant.phield.data.User;
import com.tremulant.phield.data.Venue;
import com.tremulant.phield.data.helpers.StringWithTag;
import com.tremulant.phield.webservices.WebServiceTask;
import com.tremulant.phield.webservices.WebServiceUtils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.tremulant.phield.Constants.DEFAULT_REVIEW_TEXT;

public class CreateReviewActivity extends BaseActivity implements RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener, View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
    private User mUser;
    private Venue mVenue;
    private Review mReview;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private TextView mUserTextCounter;
    private boolean mbEditTextFocusedOnce;
    private CreateReviewServiceTask mCreateReviewServiceTask;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CreateReviewActivity";
    //private RatingBar mRatingBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkUserTokensSet();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_review);
        //activateToolbarWithHomeEnabled();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

activity layout  that works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tremulant.phield.ReviewDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Phield.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Phield.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

    <include layout="@layout/content_review_details"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Content part that works and seems relevant

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.tremulant.phield.ReviewDetailsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_review_details">
```

Java activity that works

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.tremulant.phield.data.AggReview;
import com.tremulant.phield.data.User;
import com.tremulant.phield.webservices.WebServiceTask;
import com.tremulant.phield.webservices.WebServiceUtils;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ReviewDetailsActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnMapReadyCallback{

    private User mUser;
    private AggReview mAggReview;
    private ReviewTextAdapter mReviewTextAdapter;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LatLng mLatLng;
    private RetrieveReviewTextTask mRetrieveReviewTextTask;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ReviewDetailsActivity";
    private List<ReviewText> mReviewTexts = new ArrayList<ReviewText>();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(ReviewDetailsActivity.this, VenueMap.class);
        mapIntent.putExtra(VENUE_TRANSFER,mAggReview);
        startActivity(mapIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        checkUserTokensSet();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review_details);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/phieldPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/phieldPrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/phieldAccentColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/phieldBackgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Phield" parent="Theme.Base"/>

    <style name="ActionBarThemeOverlay" parent="">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/phieldPrimaryTextColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/phieldAccentColor</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/phieldBackgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/phieldBackgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/phieldPrimaryColor</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/phieldBackgroundColor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Phield.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <style name="Theme.Phield.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="Theme.Phield">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/md_black_1000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/md_black_1000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mySpinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/phieldPrimaryColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="mySpinnerSelectedItemStyle"
           parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/phieldPrimaryColor</item>
    </style>



</resources>
```

I also had tried splitting my activity_create_reviews into an activity layout with a Coordinator layout and a content layout, but this also didn't work and messed with my formatting so I reverted it. Here it is to show what I tried.

activity_create_reviews.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tremulant.phield.CreateReviewActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Phield.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Phield.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"/>

        <include layout="@layout/content_create_review"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_create_reviews.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.tremulant.phield.CreateReviewActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_create_review">

    <!--  <ScrollView

          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@color/phieldBackgroundColor"
          >-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_linear_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
        >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venue_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/phieldPrimaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"/>
            <!--etc more layouts  and things unrelate to toolbar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what I did wrong. I had setContentView twice in my activity which was causing the toolbar not to display.

Comment: Thanks!
I was troubleshooting the same thing for hours.

Comment: Have the same problem and this is not my problem. What a nightmare to make this work, compared to the old actionBar. Isn't there an Android developer that reads this and could offer help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to use toolbar you should set `noActionBar` theme for your activity(or for your Application tag) in `manifest` for example :

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

also you need to set your toolbar as actionbar for activity also overide `onCreateOptionMenu` like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 


private Toolbar toolbar;                              // Declaring the Toolbar Object


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar); // Attaching the layout to the toolbar object
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);                   // Setting toolbar as the ActionBar with setSupportActionBar() call

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added more code and tried the editions on the `onCreateOptionsMenu `and `onOptiionsItemsSelected` as well as setting my theme to `"@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"` and the only change that made was making the space where the toolbar exists white instead of my background color. Any idea why it works in the one activity and not the other?

Comment: my base theme contains `<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>` isn't this similar? I use this in almost all activities except the few I don't want a toolbar.

Comment: it is because your first activity's xml layout parent is not CoordinatorLayout. you shoud use it and use your ScrollView bottom of AppBarLayout

Comment: also add 
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to your <ScrollView> tag

Comment: I tried moving my ScrollView into a CoordinatorLayout just now and adding the appbar_scrolling_view_behavior and it looks the same.